# I cant register/add data inside mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I can't detect the problem of the code. This code here is functioning with newer version of xampp server; but when i try to implement it to old web server. there is error that i can't detect.

```
if(isset($_POST['s_i_reg'])) {
    // mysql connect function here.... (moved up here)
    $lts = $_POST['lts'];
    $uname = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
    $date = date("m/d/Y");
    $time = date("h:i:sa");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM special_instruction_access WHERE username = '$uname' AND passcode = '$pass'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die( "MySQL Error: ".mysql_error() );
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $sql1 = "SELECT * from special_instruction_reg";
    $que_sir = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die( "MySQL Error: ".mysql_error() );
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($que_sir)){
    if($lts==$row['lts']){
        $error = "LTS is already registered!";
        header('location: login.php?error=2');
    }else if(strlen($lts)==8){
        $error = "LTS is Invalid!";
        header('location: login.php?error=3');
    }else if($user !== false && strlen($lts)!==8) {
        $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM special_instruction_access");
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        if($uname==$result['username'] && $pass==$result['passcode'] && $lts!==$row['lts']){

            $que_sir1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql1) or die( "MySQL Error: ".mysql_error() );
            while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($que_sir1)){
                if($lts==$row1['lts']){
                    $confirm="true";
                }
            }
            if($confirm=="true"){
                $error = "LTS is already registered!";
                header('location: login.php?error=2');
            }else{
                mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO special_instruction_reg (lts,date,time) VALUES ('$lts','$date','$time')"); 
                mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO special_instruction_logs (username,date,time) VALUES ('$uname','$date','$time')"); 

            }
            header('location: operator.php');   
        }
        }       
    }
    else {
        $error = "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again";
        header('location: login.php?error=1');
    }   
    }
}
```

---

Xammp:
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation
PHP version: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

---

Comment: Do you have any error text or description?

Comment: what is the issue you are getting?

Comment: I checked your code, I saw you used mysqli_query, but you get mysql_error. It must mysqli_error. please change this function and post your error.

Comment: @u_mulder it doesn't show any errors. its functioning to xampp localhost (newer version). I'm trying to apply it to the (old version) wampp server.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection and it appears that you might be storing passwords in plain text rather than hashed.

Comment: what is the php version in your older version?

Comment: @RamRaider its not really an issue here. i think the mysql server or php can't detect the mysqli code

Comment: @AmanjotKaur PHP version: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Comment: You are trying to make it work on old server. What's his PHP version? Is it above 5

Comment: In xampp\apache\logs\error.log, have you got any error listed there?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I'll try all the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at PDO:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

MySQL is depracated and vulnerable to SQL injections.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

You should also never plaintext-store your passwords.
Be sure to **hash** them properly:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

On top of that, try enabling error logging by placing this on the first line after `<?php`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Then simply debug your way into the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it and make sure to feedback about the issue.

Comment: is PDO more stable?

Comment: @JayAnthonyDuran it is more efficient, yes.